# capture and stop windows messages for saving a file

Tags: windows

I have following scenario.

A third party "save file" option has two selections for "format". One is "*.abc" while other is "*.*".

That means user can save any format just like "Notepad.exe"

I know how to get handle for the software main window as well as "save as" window and "save button.

My requirement is, When user clicks the "save" button. I want to check which format it is saving. if it is "*.abc" even if "*.*" is selected, I want to allow else display a message "Not Permitted".

I am using VC++ 2010 and to best of my understanding I have to use "PreTranslatemessage"

I could find following example to disable a text box ....

```
BOOL CMyDialog:: PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
//m_MyEditBox - read only edit box
if(m_MyEditBox.m_hWnd == pMsg->hwnd)
{
  if(pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
     //Nullifying the WM_KEYDOWN message
     pMsg->wParam=NULL ;
  }
}

return CDialog:: PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
```

How can I capture and stop saving other formats. I will make a windows service to run continuously. Will make sure that when service is stopped, software is also closed so that my purpose is achieved.

I can do all other but the main task of capturing windows message on save button click and displaying "not permitted" message.

Please guide.

Comment: You want to do that for every single application user may run and not just your own one? (I'm trying to understand what's the point to have a service for this)

Comment: Why do you care? Is that a remote access or something or what? What's preventing the user from renaming the file manually afterwards? And why would you deny him doing that? What is it you're *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: I always see first answers as why you want to do? well this i hope is forum to guide programming and not why?
Still I like to say that we are encrypting a specific format and we want to stop all other formats from saving. This is user requirement and hence we do not ask him why?